# How to undelegate your account

Tags: api, delegation

is there a way to undelegate your funds?
I know I am in control of my funds all the time. But what if I just don't want to delegate any longer. Can the delegation be stopped?
If so, what command do I need to use?

Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can stop delegating using the following command: `tezos-client withdraw delegate from`

See [here](https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/cli-commands.html) for a list of all client commands.

Comment: Thank you! Is there an similar command available in the P2P RPC Interface?
I am coming from the cold wallet side which I did not mention above. Sorry for that.
So I would prefer some command/operation that can be issued through the RPC calls.

Comment: From RPC you need to run a new delegation operation; the `delegate` field is optional so just omit it for undelegation.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you!